# WordPress REST API not allowing DELETE and some POST calls

Tags: wordpress, apache, nginx, wordpress-rest-api

We run a WordPress based site where WordPress content is mostly being accessed through the REST API to run a single page application. Now for some sites we have currently in use i can't delete or change custom posts via the REST API calls. I always get a 403, permission denied. I'm pretty sure that there is no .htacess file causing this behaviour as I'm actually using another site with an almost identical setup (same docker image) where things work without problems.
The apache trace log showed the following message, which seems a bit odd but I couldn't find much info on what it actually means:

```
[core:trace3] [pid 289] request.c(304): [client 10.x.x.x:53112] request authorized without authentication by access_checker_ex hook: /wp-json/wp/v2/usernote/41674, referer:  https://xxx.yyy.com/en/legal/chapter-one/article-1/
```

after a bunch of other messages it then returns the 403:

```
[http:trace3] [pid 8878] http_filters.c(1089): [client 10.x.x.x:59686] Response sent with status 403, headers:, referer: https://xxx.yyy.com/en/legal/chapter-one/article-1/
```

creating a new post (using POST) however does work, so it's not that the http methods POST and DELETE themselves are disallowed by the looks of it...

all instances are behind a nginx reverse proxy but again, the configurations there are virtually identical (apart from different certificates and server names etc...)

i've been up and down all config files i can think of but have not been able to solve this for more than a week now.
so any hints are most appreciated!

Comment: Can you please let me know what code you are using for the post method. so I can more look into the issue.

Answer (score 0):

it turned out to be a set of missing capabilties